# Including all Dimension table rows even if no Fact table entries in SSAS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

I am processing a cube in SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services.

Is there a setting to include all rows in a Dimension table even when there are no FACT table entries for some of the Dimension rows

e.g. there are no sales for Product Type 1 in July but I would like to see it when I browse the cube, with a value of zero or null

At the moment, when my cube processes, Product type 1 does not appear for July at all. The data is not that large so I am not overly worried about cube size or processing time

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have configured your cube processing to do a "process full" of the database, or in case you do it in single steps, a "process full" of the dimension, the data should be there.

I would assume you use `NON EMPTY`in your query, and hence do not see the products without values in the fact table. If you write the MDX yourself manually, omit the `NON EMPTY` from the rows clause (or the columns clause, in case you have the products on columns). If you are using a tool that generates the MDX from what you click, normally you can configure somewhere if `NON EMPTY` should be used or not. But where exactly you do that depends on the tool you use.

Comment: Many thanks for that.  We are just browsing the cube in Excel so the issue is really there as I had set "Process full"

Comment: Just for completeness I'll add this, so simple I can't believe I missed it.  In Excel 2010 anyway it's: Pivot Table Options, Display Tab - Show Items with no data on columns/Rows checkboxes